# Mobile CSS not loading. Is my code correct?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I am trying to build a seperate CSS file for a site for mobile. The regular site was not originally built with mobile in mind, but the site now needs mobile functionality. Problem is, I am not able to get the mobile css file to load on any phone device. I have tried it on my Droid Razor in two seperate browsers, I have also tried emulating it using this: http://www.mobilephoneemulator.com/.

I can't get the mobile CSS file to load either way. I am not sure why. I set a few divs and all images to display:none; just to see if it is working, but I am not getting any results. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my links to the css files.

```
<link href="/stylesheets/css_Sanford.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 481px" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/content-sanford.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 481px" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/mobile-sanford.css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" />
```

This is the mobile CSS file code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#sliderFrame{
display:none;   
}

#slider{
display:none;   
}

img {
dipslay:none;   
}

div#player{
display:none;   
}
```

Comment: How do you know it is not loaded

Comment: @InGodITrust I think because he isn't seeing any css when he's visiting on mobile?

Comment: @KeesSonnema you mean he is seeing? He should try at least with `!important`

Comment: That could be an option yes. The problem could be another style overriding this.

Comment: I tried !important. It doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot some ")" in two first *link*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/css_Sanford.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 481px)" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/content-sanford.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 481px)" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/mobile-sanford.css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" />
```

Comment: I made a change in the css to have a *{display:none;} and that seemed to work on mobile, then everything else seems to be working now for some reason in mobile. I have no idea why. Thank you for your help guys.